# Can not import layers from tensorflow

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, package, layer

I have been installed tensorflow packages for python 3.11

And now when i import tensorflow it works fine

But when I command VS code:

```
from tensorflow import layers 
from tensorflow import ImageDataGeneretor
```

It gives me an error that is:

```
Import Error: can not import name ‘layers’ from ‘tensorflow’ 

Import Error: can not import ‘ImageDataGeneretor’ from ‘tensorflow’
```

Anyone please can help me how to fix this issue??

I only installed tensorflow packages

Comment: These are not directly in the `tensorflow` module. For instance `ImageDataGenerator` is from `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image`

Comment: What about layers?

Comment: Now you know the issue. What's left is one google search to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Layer class is in the module tensorflow.keras.layers. Here is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer). And same remark for ImageDataGenerator [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).

So the imports are:

```
# TF 2.13.1
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```